# Sorting through mixed files with appropriate foldername in their filename

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have processed over 10 000 mp4 into gifs, they have their "category" in the titles from a batch I used earlier because there's around 1000 category ( so 1000 folders) and my software could only process one folder at a time, so i batch renamed them with their parent folder (so I could sort them later) and put them in a "mother" folder. They all have randomly generated letters + titles + category in their names. Neither the categories or actual file name have the same amount of letters (in case that's relevant)
the folder and file names always start with "reddit_sub_CATEGORY".
Categories always have all lowercase, no number or special chars.

files example (there are over 10 000 of them)

```
d:\motherfolder\reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_eatdog.gif
d:\motherfolder\reddit_sub_funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s_kiotdawg_123.gif
d:\motherfolder\reddit_sub_randommemes_023093x23_uploadedtitle.gif
d:\motherfolder\reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames_92382j38du8yu_socute.gif
d:\motherfolder\reddit_sub_ and over 9001 more
```

Folders (over 1000 of them)

```
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog\
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_funnydogs\
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_randommemes\
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames\
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_ and over 999 more
```

I tried all the scripts I could find, spend many hours trying to make them work with not avail.

I actually lost the work due to a bad batch I made accidentally but i do have the batch that Made this happen.. maybe it can be worked around to do the opposite.

Update - can't find it!!
It was something along the lines of

```
ECho off
rem Enter into Root Folder
cd /d %~dp0
cd d:\rip\mp4\mothermp4
rem Process each SUB folder
for /D %%u in (*) do (
   rem Enter into the SUB folder
   cd "%%u"
   rem Process each Project
   for %%p in (*) do (
      rem Move all files one level up
      move *.* ..
      rem Go back one level up to root folder

   )
   cd ..
)
```

this one i found of this website and modified it to what I needed. but I can only find this not-working version. this one doesnt even rename yet

I expect folders to have ALL their appropriate files sorted into them.
(no copy if possible, its around 150gb!)

eg;

```
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog\reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_eatdog.gif
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s\reddit_sub_funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s_kiotdawg_123.gif
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_randommemes\reddit_sub_randommemes_023093x23_uploadedtitle.gif
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames\reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames_92382j38du8yu_socute.gif
```

updated request --- 
Removing "reddit_sub_category_" at the same time in the file name

```
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog\83j331_cutecattries-to_eatdog.gif
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s\fdsljdsd9s_kiotdawg_123.gif
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_randommemes\023093x23_uploadedtitle.gif
d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames\92382j38du8yu_socute.gif
```

Comment: Your expected result does **NOT** apply with your base `d:\sortedfolders\reddit_sub_*`  also why all those redundant prefixes `reddit_sub_` ?

Comment: 1.Woops, bad copy pasta. Edited
2.No particular reason. It's how the ripper sorts the subreddits and it doesn't bother me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree running before

```
> tree D:\ /F
D:\
├───motherfolder
│       reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_eatdog.gif
│       reddit_sub_funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s_kiotdawg_123.gif
│       reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames_92382j38du8yu_socute.gif
│       reddit_sub_randommemes_023093x23_uploadedtitle.gif
│
└───sortedfolders
    ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog
    ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs
    ├───reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames
    └───reddit_sub_randommemes
```

This batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54372309.cmd
@Echo off
Set "FileBase=D:\motherfolder"
Set "FolderBase=D:\sortedfolders"
for /d %%A in (%FolderBase%\*) Do Move "%FileBase%\%%~nA*" "%%A\"
```

and after:

```
> tree /F D:\
D:\
├───motherfolder
└───sortedfolders
    ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog
    │       reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_eatdog.gif
    │
    ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs
    │       reddit_sub_funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s_kiotdawg_123.gif
    │
    ├───reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames
    │       reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames_92382j38du8yu_socute.gif
    │
    └───reddit_sub_randommemes
            reddit_sub_randommemes_023093x23_uploadedtitle.gif
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot!!!
One more thing... can I remove the whole thing from its name?
I actually don't need it once its back in there! Totally forgot about that ^^

Comment: Do you mean to shift the folders from sortedfolders to root?

Comment: No i mean like, just remove       reddit_sub_category from all files